# Why do EXPECT_CALL tests pass unexpectedly when using a dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I am just getting started with GoogleTest and GoogleMock. Reading the ["for dummies" documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests) the example tests a `Painter` class which depends on a `Turtle`:

**Real object - Turtle.h**

```
class Turtle {
public:
    virtual ~Turtle() {}
    virtual void PenDown() = 0;
};
```

**Mock object - mock-turtle.h**

```
class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());
};
```

**Code under test - Painter.h**

```
class Painter {
public:
    Painter(Turtle *turtle){};
};
```

**Unit test - test_painter.cpp**

This is intended to test whether the `turtle.PenDown()` method is called from the `Painter` constructor.

```
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
    MockTurtle turtle;
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown())
            .Times(AtLeast(1));
    Painter painter(&turtle);
}
```

This test correctly fails because `PenDown()` is never called.

But if I change the test to use a dereferenced pointer to `MockTurtle` it **incorrectly** passes.

```
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
    MockTurtle *turtle = new MockTurtle();
    EXPECT_CALL(*turtle, PenDown())
            .Times(AtLeast(1));

    Painter painter(turtle);
}
```

Why does this test pass when using a dereferenced pointer? Nowhere in my code is `PenDown()` called.

For more context, I would like to use a pointer to `MockTurtle` so that I can initialise it in a test fixture so that other tests can use it.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Google Test and it's working as expected. Try using the latest version of Google Test

Comment: I'm also using the latest version of Google Test (pulled from github). Are you doing anything special to build your test executable? My build command is: `g++ -I googlemock/include -I googletest/include -I ../source -L googlemock -lgmock_main test_painter.cpp -o test_painter`

Comment: Nothing special but I use Visual C++ and here both tests fail

Comment: Out of interest do you have `delete turtle` at the end of your test, or is it exactly as written above?

Comment: Ya I deleted turtle by using delete after instantiating painter's object else it would result in memory leak

Comment: That seems to be the root cause, see below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't delete your pointer.

And it's not that forgetting to delete it is going to result in `PenDown()` being pushed. The member is never called. But it's the **destructor** of `MockTurtle` that reports the results to the framework.

When you leak it, nothing is reported. The framework thinks you ran an empty test (which vacuously passes), because it doesn't get any feedback.

When `turtle` is an object (not a pointer), that has automatic storage duration, its destructor is called automatically at scope exit. That's why the error is reported.

This is just GoogleMock utilizing [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) for the boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @StoryTeller's excellent answer, I thought it would be useful to add some extra background, so no-one else is caught out by this issue.

I am using CLion as my test runner and because of [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10988) the error which was occurring *after* the tests have been run was not being displayed. Running my test binary from the terminal revealed it:

```
./test_painter --gtest_filter=* --gtest_color=no
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest
[ RUN      ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething
[       OK ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.

/Users/donturner/PCode/workspace-kinetis/blinky/tests/test_painter.cpp:13: ERROR: this mock object (used in test PainterTest.CanDrawSomething) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x7fc06f402720.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
```

So I was forgetting to delete my pointer. I added the following line to the end of my test:

```
delete turtle;
```

And hey presto the test correctly fails:

```
$ ./test_painter --gtest_filter=* --gtest_color=no
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest
[ RUN      ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething
/Users/donturner/PCode/workspace-kinetis/blinky/tests/test_painter.cpp:13: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*turtle, PenDown())...
         Expected: to be called at least once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething

 1 FAILED TEST
```

If anyone can tell me why forgetting to delete a pointer results in `PenDown()` being called I would be most interested!

Comment: ya, now I can replicate this issue. Sound interesting though